# Python: color output with multiple variables

Tags: python, printing, colors, fabric, init

I'm trying to print Python output on the Terminal.

Everything works fine if I have to print a phrase, problem starts when the phrase contains variables.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
from colorama import init
init(autoreset=True)
from fabric.colors import red, green

latitude =  36.02866
longitude = 70.77258

print ("\033[92m" + 'I know I can be green' + "\033[0m")
print ("\033[92m" +'I want the whole line to be green or red',latitude,',',longitude, 'at', datetime.datetime.now(), "\033[0m")
print ("\033[91m" + 'I know I can be red' + "\033[0m")
print ('automatically back to default color again')
```

As you can see just the first part of the second phrase is colored.

[image]

But I need the whole phrase to be colored!

Comment: You already picked an answer but FYI you could've just replaced the commas in your text with `+` and it would've worked. Any kind of string concatenation will work. `print ("\033[92m" +'I want the whole line to be green or red'+str(latitude)+','+str(longitude)+ 'at'+ str(datetime.datetime.now())+ "\033[0m")` But getting used to `format()` is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by formating the string, instead of giving new parameters to the function `print()` :

```
print ("\033[92m" +'I want the whole line to be green or red {0}, {1} at {2}'.format(
    latitude, longitude, datetime.datetime.now())+ "\033[0m")
print ("\033[91m" + 'I know I can be red' + "\033[0m")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to parse it as an string. Do like this and it should work out fine. At least when I'm trying it out:

```
variable = 3
print ('%sI know I can be green var: %s %s' % ("\033[92m", variable,"\033[0m"))
```

With regards

Answer (score 0):

Try `fabric.colors`, its a great solution:

```
from fabric.colors import green, yellow, red

print(green("Id: %s Type: %s" % (instance.id,instance.instance_type)))
```